# How to Sort Array by its double Attribute?

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity populated by the following Array Object:

```
public class VideoLocation {

    public String deleted_at = null;
    public int documentary_video_length = -1;
    public int id = -1;
    public double latitude = 0d;
    public double longitude = 0d;
    public int position = -1;
    public String updated_at = null;
    public String name = null;
    public String text = null;
    public String documentary_video_url = null;
    public String documentary_thumbnail_url = null;
    public String audio_text_url = null;
    public Footage[] footages = null;

    public VideoLocation(){

    }
```

I need to sort the ListActivity based on the distance between the Location and the User.
I don't have any trouble in sorting the 'name' String alphabetically, I use this method:

```
public void sortAZ(){
    Arrays.sort(videoLocations, new Comparator<VideoLocation>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(VideoLocation lhs, VideoLocation rhs) {
            return lhs.name.compareTo(rhs.name);
        }
    });
}
```

but the method can't be used for 'double' data type, which I need for 'latitude' and 'longitude'. Besides there's no attribute 'distance' for the object VideoLocation.

How am I able to sort it out even when I can calculate the distance between the Location and the User?

**UPDATE**

**THIS IS THE FINAL SOLUTION! WORKS LIKE A CHARM**

```
public void sortNearby(){
        Arrays.sort(videoLocations, new Comparator<VideoLocation>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(VideoLocation lhs, VideoLocation rhs) {

                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();

                double lat1 = lhs.latitude;
                double lng1 = lhs.longitude;

                double lat2 = rhs.latitude;
                double lng2 = rhs.longitude;

                double lhsDistance = countDistance(lat,lng,lat1,lng1);
                double rhsDistance = countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2);
                if (lhsDistance < rhsDistance) 
                    return -1;
                else if (lhsDistance > rhsDistance) 
                    return 1;
                else return 0;
            }
        });
    }

public double countDistance(double lat1,double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
    {
        Location locationUser = new Location("point A");
        Location locationPlace = new Location("point B");
        locationUser.setLatitude(lat1);
        locationUser.setLongitude(lng1);
        locationPlace.setLatitude(lat2);
        locationPlace.setLongitude(lng2);

        double distance = locationUser.distanceTo(locationPlace);

        return distance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either give `VideoLocation` a field to hold the distance from the user, calculate that for each of your locations, and then sort with a `Comparator` that compares the distances, or make a `Comparator` that computes both distances and compares them.

The first approach requires an extra field in the `VideoLocation` which you may not want to have. The second approach does some redundant computation (computing distances something like 2n log n times instead of n times). Take your pick; either will work fine and neither is all *that* expensive.

Comment: As Igor F. says, your new code is buggy: you need to compute the latitude and longitude of both `lhs` and `rhs` (at the moment you're computing the latitude of one and the longitude of the other!), and then call `countDistance(lat,lng,lat1,lng1)` and `countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2)` (note: `lat1` and `lng`1 don't exist yet, but they will when you compute both lats and both lngs!).

Comment: I dont't really get it yet, could you provide an improvement or a correction with the code I just posted instead? That would be helpful. Thx

Answer (score 2):

To compare on doubles, you can do this:

```
@Override
public int compare(VideoLocation lhs, VideoLocation rhs) {
    double lhsDistance = ...
    double rhsDistance = ...
    if (lhsDistance < rhsDistance) return -1;
    else if (lhsDistance > rhsDistance) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`Location.distanceBetween()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) method to get the distance between the two points and the user, and then sort on that.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use some powerful tools like `Collections`...

```
ArrayList<Double> someList = new ArrayList<Double>(getDoubleListFromSomewhere());

Collections.sort(someList, new Comparator < Double>() {

public int compare(Double c1, Double c2) {

      return c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName());

    } });
```

After that you list of double values should be all sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Your code always returns 0, because lhsDistance and rhsDistance are always same:

```
double lhsDistance = countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2);
double rhsDistance = countDistance(lat,lng,lat2,lng2);
```

You haven't provided enough information, but I guess you want to compare distances between the user and a number of different locations, like:

```
double lhsDistance = countDistance(latUser, lngUser, lat, lng);
double rhsDistance = countDistance(latUser, lngUser, lat2, lng2);
```

Comment: what do u mean by latUser and lngUser? Because lat and lng actually belong to the User

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to sort a collection of geotagged objects according to their distance from one special such object: the user. So (lat, lng) and (lat2, lng2) are coordinates of two objects from the collections, and you determine how far each of them is from (latUser, lngUser).

Comment: thank you, just figured out where I went wrong. I've updated my question with the final solution